# Invalid xml response

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2008, webservice-client

I'm connecting to a new web-service.  Using Visual-Studio Add Service Reference, I get my method call as:

```
void Method(string request);
```

The problem is that the web-service sends a response, so that void should be a string?  Because I'm getting an Invalid XML error for the response.  Using **Fiddler** I can see the response as:

```
{"errorcode": "000","errormsg": "Alert Added."}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AlertResponse xmlns="http://www.quit.com/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Obviously it is invalid XML with the Json response before the XML.  How do I call/setup the service differently to get the response result?

Comment: How is the server set up now? Clearly the service is sending invalid data to the client.

Comment: I didn't setup the server.  It is a soap 1.1 or 1.2 request, both give the same response.

Answer (score 0):

It's a void method, but it's not a one-way method, so the server will send a response, but it will be an empty element, as in your case:

```
<soap:Body>
    <AlertResponse xmlns="http://www.quit.com/" />
</soap:Body>
```

The server does send a response because even in the case of `void` methods, there are other possible "responses" which it could return - an example is an exception (or a *fault*, in SOAP terms).

However, the service you're talking to is sending an invalid response. If you don't own the service, and you still need to consume it, you may want to look into creating a custom encoder which will be able to strip that extraneous JSON fragment from the response, before trying to consume it.